# How can I find duplicate integers between two arrays and copy them into a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science

To begin, I am doing this using only arrays (no hash maps or array lists).

I am trying to create a method, project, which inputs two integer arrays with different sizes.

I am trying to compare them in a way to get the following output: projecting `[1, 3, 5, 3]` to `[2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]` results in: `[1, 3, 1, 5, 3]`.
However, projecting `[2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]` to `[1, 3, 5, 3]` results in: `[1, 3, 5, 3]`.

I believe the nested for loop might be wrong as it is iterating through the first indices for the first array all the way through the second array, then going to the next.

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the starred line (`tempArray[i] == arr1[i]`, I know it shouldn't be `tempArray[i]` but not sure what exactly to put).

I'm not sure how to compare them in a way to produce the line above, as it needs to be "in order". What could be the best way to accomplish this?

I attempted the following code:

```
public int[] project(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int[] tempArray = new int[counter];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                tempArray[i] = arr1[i]; // UNDERLINED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error is gone, but now my `return` statement is: projecting `[1, 3, 5]` to `[2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]` results in: `[1, 3, 5, 0, 0]`, when it needs to be: projecting `[1, 3, 5]` to `[2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]` results in: `[1, 3, 1, 5, 3]`.

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: To clarify, my first nested for loop is to find the number of matches so that the tempArray length can be determined. I need to figure out what the length will be prior to encoding integers to it because I am not using ArrayList. No ArrayList solutions please and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your first `for` loop

change this to later

```
arr1[i] == arr2[i]
```

to

```
arr1[i] == arr2[j]
```

Regarding overlapping issues in the projection array, you need to maintain different value as your `index` rather than `i` or `j` which is used by `arr1` and `arr2` respectively

```
int[] tempArray = new int[counter];
int index = 0;

for(int i=0 ; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            tempArray[index++] = arr1[i];
        }
    }
}
```

For the values which you are expecting you should loop through `arr2` first

```
for(int j=0 ; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            tempArray[index++] = arr1[i];
        }
    }
}
```

If the contents of `array` are not hardcoded and you dont know the order in which you want to pass, you can make use of `length`

```
  int[] ans;
  if(a.length < b.length) {
      ans = project(a, b);
  } else {
      ans = project(b, a);
  }
```

Output:

> [1, 3, 1, 5, 3]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239878/discussion-on-answer-by-turtle-how-can-i-find-duplicate-integers-between-two-arr).

Answer (score 0):

You currently have index variables (`i`, `j`) tracking the indexes of each input array as you loop through them, but you also need to keep track of the write head of the result array. Initialize, say `int k = 0` before the outer `for` loop, then set the value like this: `tempArray[k++] = array1[i];`.

You can forgo the first loop If you are OK with performing a single array copy. Initialize an array as long as the second input array (since there can never be more duplicated elements than existing elements) as the tempArray. Then if you want it to fit exactly,  initialize the final array to the exact length `k` and use `System#arrayCopy`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I tried using a k but it seems the issue was I should've used k++ as you state. However, after adding this, my output is now Projecting [1, 3, 5] to [2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3] results in: [1, 1, 3, 3, 5]. My output is meant to be Projecting [1, 3, 5] to [2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3] results in: [1, 3, 1, 5, 3]. So, it seems to be printing it in the wrong order. It needs to be in the order of the second array (say, if 1 occurs in the 1st indice then in the 3rd, it will be in those places for the resulting array).

Answer (score 0):

this will probably solve your problem

```
public int[] project(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i : arr2) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, i) >= 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    int[] arr4 = new int[counter];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i : arr2) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, i) >= 0) {
            arr4[index++] = i;
        }
    }

    return arr4;
}
```

Comment: Hi hani, thank you for your help. Unfortunately I cannot use libraries such as binarySearch, but I will review your answer to help me understand to do this in a different way. I am trying to do this using only arrays without array helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

The nested iteration is expensive, so we want to avoid that.  The first thing to do is sort the array we are projecting from so we can perform a binary search on it.  Second, don't execute the nested iteration to determine the output array size.  Create an array the size of the array we are projecting to since it can be no longer than that.

```
public int[] projection(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] temp = new int[b.length];
  int nextIndex = 0;
  for (int x : b) {
    if (contains(a, x)) {
      temp[nextIndex++] = x;
    }
  }
  return slice(temp, nextIndex);
}

private boolean contains(int[] array, int value) {
  for (int element : array) {
    if (element == value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

private int[] slice(int[] src, int size) {
  int[] slice = new int[size];
  for (int index = 0 ; index < size ; ++index) {
    slice[index] = src[index];
  }
  return slice;
}
```

Comment: Hi vsfDawg, it is in fact expensive but I am meaning to figure this problem out without using helper methods like binarySearch unfortunately, so I am trying to figure out how to do this (in both orders of projection) without using binarySearch or any System commands.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the sorting/binary-search and even the array-copy.

Comment: Hi vsfDawg, I attempted this code but for some reason the output was [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I will try to figure out why.

Comment: @annas1019 I tried it with the inputs from the OP and it produced the expected outputs.  What inputs are you providing to it?

Comment: I am using the same inputs as the OP. I want to mention that the array being projected to CAN be shorter than the first array, such as in the case where Projecting [2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3] to [1, 3, 5, 3] results in: [1, 3, 5, 3].

Comment: @annas1019 the for-loop was incrementing `size` rather than `index` in the `slice(..)` method.  Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, I think, in your temporary array, you should be saving the values from `arr2[j]` instead of `arr1[i]`.

Also, you need a different counter (set to 0 initially and incremented in the loop) for setting the values in `tempArray[counter]`.

What I mean exactly is:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            tempArray[counter] = arr2[j];
            counter++;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your help. By second problem, do you mean the output:Projecting [1, 3, 5] to [2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3] results in: [1, 3, 5, 0, 0]? We actually managed to fix this issue, however the new issue is that when attempting projection in the opposite order [2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]  to [1, 3, 5], the output should be [1, 3, 5] however it's getting [1, 1, 3, 3, 5].

Comment: Yes, I mean to fix the projection problem. I think this piece of code should work for all the cases, i.e  your temporary array should consider the order of elements of array2 with correct number of values.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly , [1,2,4] and [1,5,6,7,2,1,4] should return [1,2,1,4], correct? I mean, take all the values from array2 that are present in array1 and put them in another array.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried your method, but it does get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: Make sure you create tempArray with correct size, or for debugging, just put arr2.length as tempArray size for a while. Try to fix this part on you own.